# Ignoring powershell script failure for a particular line

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exit-code, start-process

I have a powershell script that defines `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`
But i also have a `start-process` call that target a process that returns a non-standard exit code on success (1 instead of 0).
As a result of this, the script is failing even when the start-process is ok.
I tried to append the `-ErrorAction "Continue"` parameter in the `start-process` call but it didn't solve the problem.

The problematic line looks like this:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
...
start-process "binary.exe" -Wait -ErrorAction "Continue"
if ($LastExitCode -ne 1)
{
   echo "The executable failed to execute properly."
   exit -1
}
...
```

How could I prevent start-process from making the whole script fail.

Comment: Have you tried setting `$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"` on the previous line, and then `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` on the following line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Start-Process` doesn't update `$LASTEXITCODE`. Run `Start-Process` with the `-PassThru` parameter to get the process object, and evaluate that object's `ExitCode` property:

```psh
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
...
$p = Start-Process "binary.exe" -Wait -PassThru
if ($p.ExitCode -ne 1) {
  echo "The executable failed to execute properly."
  exit -1
}
```